# How to make 5 different buttons that have NO duplicate titles in swift

Tags: ios, swift, button

```
let but1:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
let but2:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
let but3:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
let but4:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
let but5:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))

//set random numbers
override func viewDidLoad(){
    var but1String:String = self.numberArray[but1]
    var but2String:String = self.numberArray[but2]
    var but3String:String = self.numberArray[but3]
    var but4String:String = self.numberArray[but4]
    var but5String:String = self.numberArray[but5]
    var checker = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
    var combinedButValue = but1 + but2 + but3 + but4 + but5
    // make sure all the buttons are unique unique
    // then set the titles to the converted strings

    if but1String != but2String && but1String != but3String && but1String != but4String && but1String != but5String {
        button1.setTitle(but1String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
    if but2String != but1String &&  but2String != but3String && but2String != but4String && but2String !=      but5String{
        button2.setTitle(but2String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    if but3String != but1String && but3String != but2String && but3String != but4String && but3String != but5String {
        button1.setTitle(but3String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    if but4String != but1String && but4String != but2String && but4String != but3String && but4String != but5String {
        button1.setTitle(but4String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    if but5String != but1String && but5String != but2String && but5String != but3String && but4String != but5String {
        button1.setTitle(but5String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

I am trying to make the five different buttons have no duplicate titles like two "3"'s. This program does run with no errors but I am still getting multiple copies of each number. Does anyone know how to fix this or make the buttons have titles unique to themselves???

Comment: Look up "random shuffle "!

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer? Is it not working anymore?